# Name these symmetric polynomials over non-commutative variables...

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, symmetric-polynomials

Given a set of $N$ non-commutative variables $x_k$. Is there a special name for [symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial) of homogenous degree $d$ of the form that all $x_k$s appear with exponent at most $1$ at a time? So the appearance of $x_k^2$ is forbidden.

**EDIT** I mean, for every term subsequent factors $x_k$ and $x_l$ are never equal.

Some examples for $N=3$ and $d=2$:

- $P_0(x)=x_0x_1+x_1x_0+x_0x_2+x_2x_0+x_1x_2+x_2x_1$

and $d=3$:

- $P_1(x)=x_0x_1x_0+x_0x_2x_0+x_1x_0x_1+x_1x_2x_1+x_2x_0x_2+x_2x_1x_2$
- $P_2(x)=x_0x_1x_2+x_0x_2x_1+x_1x_0x_2+x_1x_2x_0+x_2x_0x_1+x_2x_1x_0$
- $P_3(x)=nP_1(x) +mP_2(x)$

The total number of possible elements in a polynomial is $N(N-1)^{d-1}$.

Comment: Noncommutative symmetric function
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncommutative_symmetric_function

Noncommutative Symmetrical Functions
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870885710328

Noncommutative analogs of symmetric polynomials
http://magweb.math.uni.wroc.pl/analiza/bedlewo12/Presentations/Burnecki.pdf

Comment: These are simply tensors of order 2 and 3 respectively.

Comment: @Surb so the order is $d$? But this would also fit if I drop the additional constraint about the exponents of $x_k$. Maybe my "tensors" could further be specified. Any idea?